# How to calculate the camera 3D position if I know 4 points in the picture of the camera

Tags: projective-geometry, vector-spaces

I've got a picture of - let's say a - table and I measured 4 Points on this table. I define my table as "ground level", so my Points got the coordinates (px, py, 0). Is it possible to calculate the camera position? (I am also able to undistort the picture (remove the camera distortion) if required).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is standard in aereal imagery and you can find hints for solutions there, e.g. [on this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthophoto), whereas [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_rectification) is probably closer to what will be of help to you.

Comment: Is the solution even unique? Or do I have to know at least the hight of the camera?

Comment: The solution is unique except for the sign of the height, but that isn't a problem because one knows that the picture was taken from above ground.